# Foundation: margin between columns

Tags: css, html, zurb-foundation

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="right-content" class="large-9 columns wrapper">

      <%= render "users/tabs", :user => @player_profile.user %>

    </div>

    <div class="large-3 columns wrapper">

      <%= render "shared/social", :resource => @player_profile %>

    </div>

</div>
```

**Preview**
[image]

And I would make something like in Fancy.com (some margin between right content and the sidebar)

[image]

I've tried with

```
<div id="right-content" class="large-9 columns wrapper" style="
    margin-right: 20px;
">
```

but in this case, the sidebar fly away below "right-content". How could i solve? 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED dealing with **padding** instead of **margins**!